# How to use Keras tf.data with generator ( flow_from_dataframe ) ? to form a perfect input pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, pipeline

**Using the input pipelines with tf.data**

[Generating the Dataset using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5ps5.png)

[The output I got after fitting the model with the train_dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJuok.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow this example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) and [this example](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/flowers_tf_lite.ipynb). These two simple examples demonstrate how to use input data pipeline. Hope This helps. Thanks!